# Listas dependientes en Laravel con relacion muchos a muchos

Tags: laravel, relaciones

estoy hace tiempo con este tema de las relaciones laravel y no logro hacer funcionar las listas dependientes. Les paso a mostrar el código.
Necesito que en la vista create donde tengo 2 select option   profesional y tratamiento, al seleccionar el profesional solo me traiga el tratamiento relacionado a ese profesional, donde la relacion la tengo en mi tabla pivot. Se que el problema esta en el controlador, pero no se como solucionarlo.
Agradezco infinitamente la ayuda de todos.

Tabla:

```
Profesionales
id
apellido

Tratamiento
id
descripcion

Profesionales_tratamientos (tabla pivot)
profesionales_id
tratamiento_id
```

Modelo Profesionales

```
public function tratamientos()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tratamiento::class,'profesionales_tratamientos','profesionales_id','tratamiento_id');
    
}
```

Modelo tratamientos

```
   public function profesionales()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Profesionales::class,'profesionales_tratamientos','tratamiento_id','profesionales_id');
     
}
```

Controlador Turno

```
public function create()
    {
        $profesionales = Profesionales::all();
        $tratamiento = Tratamiento::where('estado','=','Activo')->get();
        return view('turno.create', compact('profesionales', 'tratamiento'));

    }
```

Vista create

```
 <select name="profesional" class="form-control">
           <option selected>--Seleccione Profesional--</option>
           @foreach ($profesionales as $profesional)
                    @if (old('profesional')==$profesional->id)
                        <option value={{$profesional->id}} selected>{{ $profesional->apellido }}</option>
                    @else
                        <option value={{$profesional->id}} >{{ $profesional->apellido }}</option>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
    </select>


<div class="form-group">
              <label for="">Tratamiento:</label>
              <select class="form-control" tabindex="7" name="tratamiento" aria-label="Default select example">
              <option value="">--Seleccione tratamiento--</option>
                @foreach($tratamiento as $tratamiento)            
                @if (old('tratamiento')==$tratamiento->id)
                        <option value={{$tratamiento->id}} selected>{{ $tratamiento->descripcion }}</option>
                    @else
                        <option value={{$tratamiento->id}} >{{ $tratamiento->descripcion }}</option>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
```

route

```
Route::resource('turno','App\Http\Controllers\turnoController');
```

Comment: No se termina de entender, ¿cuál es el problema en la pregunta?

Comment: uy perdón.. lo que puse arriba en el relato
Necesito que en la vista create donde tengo 2 select option profesional y tratamiento, al seleccionar el profesional solo me traiga el tratamiento relacionado a ese profesional, donde la relacion la tengo en mi tabla pivot.

Comment: Necesitas Ajax para que cuando se seleccione un elemento del primer Select se haga una petición y se llene el segundo Select

Comment: Tenga o no la relacion de muchos a muchos creada es necesario ajax?, pensé que al tener la relacion entre modelos habia algun metodo que me traia el dato, entonces para que servirían las relaciones? sólo para el delete en cascada?

Comment: Estas confundiendo funcionalidades, las relaciones te van a servir? definitivo, por qué me recomendaste entonces ajax? por que así evitarás que la página se recargue al momento de que un select se llene y tengas que cargar la data con el otro

Comment: Entendido, al margen de que la pagina se recargue o no, mi controlador está bien? no creo que sea asi como deba hacerlo para que me traigan los tratamientos dependiendo del profesional. no?